# How can I change the the string contents in String array using enhanced-for loops?

Tags: java, arrays, string, foreach

I'm a beginner in Java I have some questions regarding the enhanced for loop and string arrays.
In the source code below, I've been trying to change the contents of the arrays using the enhanced-for loops.
It seems that I can't change the contents in the the String array(arrString), but I don't know exactly why. (It works fine for StringBuilder objects.)
I am a bit confused because I could actually do operations like str1+=str2 and change the String contents (although this operation is done via StringBuilder class) in normal situations.

Can anyone point out why this is happening and if there's any misunderstanding on my part?

```
class EnhancedForTest{
    public static void main(String[] args){ 
        //StringBuilder
        StringBuilder[] arrStringBuilder=new StringBuilder[]{new StringBuilder("Hello1"), new 
StringBuilder("Hello2"),new StringBuilder("Hello3")};
        for(StringBuilder e: arrStringBuilder){
            e.append("!"); 
        }
        for(StringBuilder e:arrStringBuilder){
            System.out.println(e);
        }
        
        //String
        String[] arrString=new String[]{"Hello1","Hello2","Hello3"};
        for(String s:arrString){
            s+="!";
        }
        for(String s:arrString){
            System.out.println(s);
        }
    }
}
```

The results are as follows(Sorry I didn't add the results!):

```
Hello1!
Hello2!
Hello3!
Hello1
Hello2
Hello3
```

P.S.: I've taken out the printing line as a new for loop, it still works for StringBuilder but not String

Comment: Please include the expected vs actual output. It is a good start to give us code we can run ourselves, but in general, it is helpful to have the information about the output right there in the question, too.

Comment: It does not work because strings are immutable and you try to assign a new value `s = ...`  - for StringBuilders you do not create a new one, you mutate the original one.

Comment: @JanezKuhar I've tried getting the print code outside and still works for the StringBuilder but not for String class! And I've just added the semicolon.

Comment: As written above, `String` is immutable, so when you change `s += "!";` a new String is created (not the same as in the `arrString`) which is referred by a local variable `s`.  If you need to modify the contents of String array, use reference to the array element: `for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) { arrString[i] += "!"; }`

Comment: Thanks everyone for your replies! I now get why it didn't work for String class. Because operations like 'code' str1+=str2; gets done by StringBuilder class, I misconceived that they will return the same initial reference. That was a total misunderstanding, as a new instance of StringBuilder will be created, and the toString() will be called like 'code' (new StringBuilder(str1).append(str2)).toString(). And the reference value for this new instance will be stored in the local variable in the for loop.

Answer (score 0):

On each iteration of the for-each loop the variable obtains a reference to the corresponding element of the array. In the case of `for(StringBuilder e:arrStringBuilder)` on the first iteration a new variable `e` of type StringBuilder will point to the same object as `arrStringBuilder[0]`. Then you call `append` using this reference, which performs operations on the object pointed by both references `e` and `arrStringBuilder[0]`. On the next iteration `e` will be assigned reference to `arrStringBuilder[1]`, but the changes made in `arrStringBuilder[0]` will stay.

In the case of `for(String s:arrString)` on the first iteration a new variable `s` will be created pointing to `arrString[0]`. However, when you do `s += '!'` you actually perform `s = s + '!'`, so you assign to this temporary variable `s` a reference to the new String object, which will contain `Hello1!`. This new object, however, is not related in any way to the original `arrString[0]` object, and at the start of the next iteration is just discarded. Your loop works like this:

```java
for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
   // Create a temporary variable which points to the same object as arrString[i]
   String s = arrString[i];
   // Create a temporary object which keeps the result of concatenation of s and '!'
   String temporary = s + '!';
   // Replace the reference stored in s with the reference to the temporary object
   s = temporary;
   // Now there is no connection between s and arrString[i]
   // And here we just discard both temporary objects 's' and 'temporary'
   // arrString[i] object remains unchanged.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`e.append("!");` is a call to a method, whose specific purpose is to modify `e`.

`s+="!";` is not a method call.  It is exactly equivalent to this:

```
s = s + "!";
```

This does not alter the state of any object.  It merely creates a *new String object* (that is, a String whose text value is the old value of `s` plus "!"), and assigns that to the *variable* `s`.  You are changing what `s` holds, but you didn’t modify the original String object that `s` used to hold.

It turns out there are no methods of String which will modify the String object, because Strings are immutable, by design.  On the other hand, the `StringBuilder` class exists specifically to create and work with changeable text values.